# Is it arriving the javascript later than the html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the size of a pop-up and give it the same width than the screen, sent from an iframe.

```
var screen_width = parent.screen.width;
```

Then I got the html:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://www.google.com','popup', 'width='"+screen_width+"',height=400px')">
```

I've tryed all possible convinations with the ' " or whatever I know, but I think it should work lie this. 
Sorry if it's obvious, my coding skills are not so developed, but I think, it's possible, html it's loading before javascript?

P.D.: One more thing, I want to use a variable, because I want to change a bit the real size of the screen.

Comment: Why not just put your screen width in your `onclick`?  No variable needed.

Comment: I'm confused, how do I do that? I thought I was trying that

Comment: Don't use the `var screen_width = parent.screen.width` stuff, just put `'width=parent.screen.width,height=400px'` straight into the HTML

Comment: ok, I thought about that, I'm sorry, one more thing, the width must be 25% less that the screen width, I thought that just trying first time with the whole screen width was cool to start, that's it! But the truth is that I need to touch a bit the screen width before, that's why the variable

Comment: @juanma Just use `Math.floor(window.screen.width * 0.75)`.

Comment: Boing Brad!! That's the key! Math.floor, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you might be having is that in your `window.open()` options, you shouldn't specify `px`... just put the number for your height.

In any case, here's a better implementation of what you're trying to do.  In your HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" data-fullpopup>Click me!</a>
```

This way, your link will work, and will even open in a new tab/window if your JavaScript doesn't run for some reason.  This is a good fallback.  The key here is the `data-fullpopup` attribute, which we'll look for in your JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.target.matches('a[data-fullpopup]')) {
      return;
    }
    window.open(e.target.href, 'popup', 'width=' + window.screen.width + ',height=400');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Basically, we wait for the document to fully load so that we can attach a click handler to the `body` element.  (Note: If you're only doing this for a couple links, it's better to attach the click handler directly to them.  I'm attaching it to `body` here, assuming that you'll have a lot of these sorts of links... it's more efficient to have one click handler in those cases.  Remember though that then this click handler has to run for every click for any element on the page.  Choose your tradeoff for your use case.)

Once the link is clicked, we confirm that it's a link with our `data-fullpopup` attribute.  If it is, we treat it like a full-width popup.  We get the target (the element) `href` on the fly, as well as the current screen width.  Finally, we prevent the default action so that it also doesn't navigate to the page on its own.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5p0xk98/3/

Comment: Super good Brad, I think I'm going to use bouth of your pieces of code geezer!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do this without setting a variable first:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://www.google.com','popup','width=document.documentElement.clientWidth,height=400')">Click Me</a>
```